# mysql, select all from table

Tags: mysql, union

I have this table.

I want to select cat id = 4  and every other row its cat parent id equals to.
e.g.  if I want all categories from cat id 4, it should result to  cat ids 4 (itself), 2 and 1

```
+-------------------------------+
| id   |  catname  | catparentid |
+-------------------------------+
|1     |  home     |    0        |
|2     |  products |    1        |
|3     |  men      |    2        |
|4     |  women    |    2        |
|5     |  shirts   |    3        |
|6     |  outdoor  |    0        |
+-------------------------------+
```

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM categories c
where c.id = 4 
c.catparentid IN (SELECT id FROM categories)
```

But it brings up all. Do I need to do a union?

Comment: what depth are you looking for? should it recursively keep finding things which ever match or should it look for just 2-3 levels down...

Comment: This article has some information you might find useful: [Managing hierarchical data in MySQL](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/database-design/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql)

Comment: as many as it can untill it equals to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN (SELECT catparentid FROM categories where id = 4) a
ON c.catparentid = a.catparentid
```

Comment: I see now that you need some recursive solution. My query certainly won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Union won't help here because you don't know how many unions you need (depth of the tree).

Newer SQL standards support the calculation of the transitive closure, I think using WITH, but I don't know how much support is available in current SQL servers.